# Looking for best Google Solution for mapping GPS points in custom application or webpage in .Net / SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, gps, cellular-network

Large quantity of GPS devices in the field with varying "heartbeats" of coordinates relayed over cellular network to dedicated SQL box with .Net frontend.  Would like to utilize Google Earth within application for mapping and tracking selected units.  Any suggestions on which Google product and associated API is most applicable?

Answer (score 1):

try this. navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition will use the GPS to get current location on mobile devices.

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation
```